# How do I normalize Non-CSV data in Encog

Tags: c#, neural-network, normalization, normalize, encog

So I'm using Jeff Heaton's Neural Network library.

When trying to solve the Iris plant classification problem I have an issue with data normalization.

I am able to Normalize a CSV file using the following method:

```
public void NormalizeFile(FileInfo SourceDataFile, FileInfo NormalizedDataFile, FileInfo NormalizationConfigFile)
    {

        var wizard = new AnalystWizard(_analyst);
        wizard.Wizard(SourceDataFile, _useHeaders, AnalystFileFormat.DecpntComma);
        var norm = new AnalystNormalizeCSV();
        norm.Analyze(SourceDataFile, _useHeaders, CSVFormat.English, _analyst);
        norm.ProduceOutputHeaders = _useHeaders;
        norm.Normalize(NormalizedDataFile);

        // save normalization configuration, which can be used later to denormalize to get the raw output.
        _analyst.Save(NormalizationConfigFile);

    }
```

So far so good... The program works with a high degree of accuracy.

The problem occurs when I want to enter the values into my console application.

I have some input data

- sepal width
- sepal length
- petal width
- petal length

Each of these values has a different high/low I would like to normalize these values so that I can feed them into my network without writing a CSV file to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later realised that what I really needed as an analyser that would all me to automatically normalise a mixture of qualitative (nominal) and quantitive data (just like the CSV implementation).

The problem was that the existing code was tightly coupled to CSV files. To combat this I wrote my own encog extension method library.

it can be found here: https://github.com/KiransHub/encog-dotnet-core

Here's an example of it in action:

```
    public void NormalizeDataExample()
    {
        List<LoadedMarketData> AppleMarketData = GetMarketData("AAPL");
        List<LoadedMarketData> MicrosoftMarketData = GetMarketData("MSFT");
        List<LoadedMarketData> YahootMarketData = GetMarketData("YHOO");

        List<LoadedMarketData> MarketData = new List<LoadedMarketData>();
        MarketData.AddRange(AppleMarketData);
        MarketData.AddRange(MicrosoftMarketData);
        MarketData.AddRange(YahootMarketData);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet().Convert(MarketData, "Market DataSet");
        var analyst = new EncogAnalyst();
        var wizard = new AnalystWizard(analyst);
        wizard.Wizard(dataSet);

        var normalizer = new AnalystNormalizeDataSet(analyst);
        var normalizedData = normalizer.Normalize(dataSet);


    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have looked and did not see the extension in the encog solution you provided. AnalystNormalizeDataSet ?

Comment: @ComputerAidedTradingSystems so there used to be a c# project. I'm looking for this on github but I can't find it now. There's a .NET Core project but that doesn't seem to contain the class anywhere. I've since moved to Tensorflow using Python.

Comment: Hi Prime, sure, tensor works, the git link for those that are interested is https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core. MS has a AI package, think they are now at release 0.5, you can use it to do tensor as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](http://www.heatonresearch.com/comment/2906#comment-2906) you can do this easily using `Encog.Util.Arrayutil.NormalizeArray` like so :

I assume your data stored in `double[]`

```
Encog.Util.Arrayutil.NormalizeArray normalizer = new Encog.Util.Arrayutil.NormalizeArray();
var normalizedData = normalizer.Process(dataMatrix, 0, 1);//(yourdata, low, high)
```

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, I did try this method myself but I don't seem to get the same results as the file based normalization. Perhaps I'm doing something else wrong. Thanks for your help... I will focus my efforts on the Encog.Util.Arrayutil.NormalizeArray class.

Comment: @PrimeByDesign could you provide me with some of the results from the file based normalization ?

Comment: I would have to run it through but this is what I do... I do a file normalization and segregate into eval and training data. I control how the data is shuffled by manually supplying the program with a  pre-shuffled file (rather than using encog to shuffle). This way I can tell which record is which. I then manually enter data from the evaluation dataset.It works most of the time but it often fails on some of the records which passed in the evaluation phase. It's hard for me to provide you with results as they vary each time the application is run. (It trains each time).

Comment: The problem is I am not able to normalize class data as this requires equilateral encoding. The encog analyst does this for CSV data but not for class data.